# Authentication request going to a page not specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I try to exhaust all my own resources before coming here and bothering the community with a very specific question that is doubtless my own screw up, but I've exhausted them now.

I'm doing an MVC3 site, built mostly with Steven Sanderson's Mvc Scaffolding package from NuGet.  (It's also using SQL CE EF Code First, and EricEJ's SqlCeMembership package.) Everything's going along  swimmingly.

Until I add an [Authorize(Users="admin")] on some controller methods that I don't want to be publicly available.

And then I get a 404 error specifying a Request URL "/Account/Login" as not being found.

The mystifying thing is that nowhere in my site is there a request for /Account/Login.  The authentication section from the web config is:

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
   </authentication>
```

Note, "LogOn", not "Login".  In fact, I have done a Cntl-F (Find) for the string "Login" (case insensitve, match whole word) over the Entire Solution, and can't find anything.  I then went on and did a Find-In-Files over the entire disk and couldn't find anything meaningful.

I'm sure it's something stupid that I have done, because if I create a new Mvc project and add an Authorize attribute to one of the methods, it works fine, going to Account/LogOn.   But I have no idea what I've done, and I'm out of ideas on how to find it.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Did you find the answer?  I have the same problem - have a MVC app with no Account controller at all (custom login code) - but there's still some reference to this Account Controller kicking around that I can't find.

Comment: No, Chris, I never did find it.  I ended up creating an Account/Login to do what I wanted (in my case, I don't want anybody that doesn't know what they're doing logging in, so I just presented a view that said that content was restricted.)  But I never did figure out where the request was coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Have you tried changing/setting the loginUrl setting in the config file?

```
    <appSettings>
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Login.asp" />
</appSettings>
```

(Obviously change the path to your requirement)

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

@Dave

I also had this same issue and found that I had mistakenly added the account folders log-on files to my projects root directory. After I deleted them I was able use [Authorize] on a controller that routed correctly to the LogOn page.